# Entity framework together with membership in code first scenario

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, membership-provider

I want to use the entity framework code-first approach for an asp.net mvc application together with the standard membership provider. The registered users will have posts etc which will link to the user via the userid in the users table. I want the posts and the other objects that point to a user be POCO classes (not inherit from any ef class). But the membership tables are not code-first, so what would be the best way to set this up?

Edit: I found http://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/. What I don't like though is that my own objects (blogposts etc) should also be included in the membership datacontext that they have built. I'd like to create another datacontext for my own objects to keep things neatly separate and maintainable, but there does not seem to be any option in EF to facilitate communication between different datacontexts.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no simple solution to this. I would leave the Membership as a stand alone database and not attempt any deep integration such as generating EF entities for the Membership objects.

As a simple solution I created a User entity within my EF model with some additional properties over the standard ASP.NET User - such as Address etc (you could use Profiles for this of course but that can come witha big performance hit). Then have a foreign key in the EF User object pointing to the ASP.NET User.

Then have calculated properties for properties which are tracked by ASP.NET Membership (ie the EF User object queries the ASP.NET Membership provider for properties such as Email to avoid data duplication).

Note that this is not an ideal solution as if Microsoft changes the ASP.NET Membership schema  your code could break as noted [here](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/03/05/38558/)

Comment: Nice, definitely an option to consider.